# Can I use NCover on Azure Emulator? Why I can't find w3wp.exe toattach in NCover?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, azure, code-coverage, ncover

So, at work, we are trying to use NCover Desktop for code coverage on a cloud based azure web application. 
We are using Azure SDK V1.8 and Visual Studio 2010.

I researched online for answer and found some article a little bit helpful in setting up environment and stuff. Following is the procedure I'm following for this.

1. Create new NCover project and select auto config
2. Reset IIS and detect w3wp.exe process
3. Start application and select/deselect executable.

Problem is, I think VS is running on localhost rather than IIS, that's why even after restarting IIS, I'm not able to detect w3wp.exe process to attach.

how can I fix this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

So, After pointing our site towards IIS - Following is the error messasge I am getting. 
I also tried to change port so there is not conflicts.

[image]

Comment: Don't run your app in iisExpress. Set up proper IIS for your app.

Comment: Disregard the Azure emulator. Set up local IIS, create a web-site there, point that site to your web-project. Connect NDepend to w3wp.exe. All guides are googleable pretty easy.